# Order tags with matches at the top

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I fetch tags from a database and I want to sort the tags that have matches in the table `tag_posts` at the top of the result. It is close to working, but I get duplicates because of the group by `c_p_id`. But if I remove `c_p_id` from the group by the order by sometimes fetches the wrong row. Would it make more sense to use some IF EXIST option?

I want the tags to be listed like this:

```
TAG B
TAG A
TAG C
```

If TAG-B has a hit in `tag_posts`.

```
SELECT c_p_id, t_id, t_title
FROM tags
LEFT JOIN projects
ON p_id = " . $p_id . "
LEFT JOIN tag_posts
ON tp_t_id = t_id
LEFT JOIN cats
ON c_id = tp_c_id
AND c_p_id = p_id
GROUP BY t_id, c_p_id
ORDER BY c_p_id DESC, t_title ASC
```

// EDIT. I figured out a different solution that is doing what I want:

```
SELECT t_id, t_title, 
    (SELECT 1 FROM tag_posts
        INNER JOIN cats
            ON c_id = tp_c_id
        INNER JOIN projects
            ON p_id = c_p_id
        WHERE tp_t_id = t_id
            AND p_id = " . $p_id . "
        LIMIT 1) used
FROM tags
ORDER BY used DESC, t_title ASC
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
SELECT t_id, t_title, 
    (SELECT 1 FROM tag_posts
        INNER JOIN cats
            ON c_id = tp_c_id
        INNER JOIN projects
            ON p_id = c_p_id
        WHERE tp_t_id = t_id
            AND p_id = " . $p_id . "
        LIMIT 1) used
FROM tags
ORDER BY used DESC, t_title ASC
```